# I want to show multiple pages preview in canvas html tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show PDF file with multiple pages in canvas html tag like this:

`<canvas class="pdfViewer hidden" style="border: solid 1px black;width: 100%;"></canvas>`

The library which I'm using is jsPDF. But, its showing single page preview only using this code.

```
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

$("input[type='file']").on("change", function (e) {
    $("button[name='Preview']").removeClass("hidden");
    var file = e.target.files[0]
    if (file.type == "application/pdf") {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function () {
            var pdfData = new Uint8Array(this.result);
            // Using DocumentInitParameters object to load binary data.
            var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
            loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
                console.log('PDF loaded');
                // Fetch the first page
                var pageNumber = 1;
                pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
                    console.log('Page loaded');

                    var scale = 1.5;
                    var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

                    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                    var canvas = $(".pdfViewer")[0];
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;

                    // Render PDF page into canvas context
                    var renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: context,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };
                    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                    renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                        console.log('Page rendered');
                    });
                });
            }, function (reason) {
                // PDF loading error
                console.error(reason);
            });
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
});
```

I want it in multiple pages like if PDF is of 5-10 pages then  should show that many number of pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a div to append `<canvas>` to render multiple pages.

I modify your code and it works, like this:

**HTML**

```html
<div id='pdf-viewer'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
var thePdf = null;
var scale = 1.5;
function renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
    thePdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
        viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        page.render({ canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport });
    })
};

var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

$("input[type='file']").on("change", function (e) {
    $("button[name='Preview']").removeClass("hidden");
    var file = e.target.files[0]
    if (file.type == "application/pdf") {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function () {
            var pdfData = new Uint8Array(this.result);
            var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
            loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {

                thePdf = pdf;
                viewer = document.getElementById('pdf-viewer');

                for(page = 1; page <= pdf.numPages; page++) {
                  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    
                  canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas';         
                  viewer.appendChild(canvas);            
                  renderPage(page, canvas);
                }
                  
            }, function (reason) {
                // PDF loading error
                console.error(reason);
            });
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. But is it possible if I choose to use it by <canvas class="pdfViewer hidden" style="border: solid 1px black;width: 100%;"></canvas>

Comment: I wan to use it by `<canvas class="pdfViewer hidden" style="border: solid 1px black;width: 100%;"></canvas>`

Comment: NO, it only works when one page maps to one canvas.

Comment: What is `canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas';  `? Is it necessary to add it or can we remove it ? Will it work after removing this?

Comment: It's just for css for adding some borders around canvas or something effect you want. It can be removed.

Comment: The code you sent is not working with Class of div. I want to get the class of div and show it in particular div. Also, when I use it with class it's throwing error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: viewer.appendChild is not a function`

Comment: I don't know what you want for other features. At least my sample code works for your **MULTIPLE PDF PAGES** requirements.